# A feature request:gender in a member's profile page

Tags: feature-request

It's a hassle to write he/she, him/her, his/her when you refer to a member whose gender is unknown.
So I suggest gender be added to the profile page of a member.

**EDIT(Aug. 19, 2003)**
Since some members don't want to make their gender public, I would like to suggest the following feature request.

There be the following options regarding gender of a member in the profile page.

1. male
2. female
3. unspecified(default)

If you choose the option 3, you are not supposed to complain when you are referred to he(or she).

**Remark** The option 3 is default. This prevents people from guessing that a person who chooses it is female.

Comment: Please tell me why you disagree with the request.

Comment: This would make no difference in many cases, as certain people (myself included) would not fill it in. Just call people by their name, or alternate between calling them male and female (this keeps people on their toes!). Call the OP the OP.

Comment: @user1729 For example, when I called a member "she" whose name is Leslie, I was told that he was male.
This conversation would be better avoided.

Comment: WP: [Gender-specific and gender-neutral pronouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutral_pronoun), [Singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). In fact, I've learned about them here at MSE, see [this older discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/gender-neutral-pronouns-they-zie-hir).

Comment: I downvoted this. First, as I do not consider it as useful. And, second, as it is a bit more complicated. One rather could not *only* ask "m or f" *at least* there ought to be the option of not declaring it preserved (which then would not really solve the problem to be solved completely), but likely this would not even be sufficient. And, if somebody wishes to make their gender known it is easy enough via mentioning something in "about" for example.

Comment: I have to admit, it is a bit irritating when people say "Thanks dude!" and "Thanks for the help, man!"...but as irritating as it is, I like the profiles the way they are now. Putting a gender field into profiles almost strikes as a dating forum. Now that I think about it, those are the only types of forums that make any real effort to clarify the gender of its users (that I know of).

Comment: I agree that this would help us with grammar. OTOH as evidenced by the responses in [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9227/11619) many women don't want to disclose their femininity in the internet. Doing so exposes them to unwelcome advances, threats even. Or if not that, draws attention to their gender and away from their math. Our grammatical difficulties do not carry much weight in comparison to their safety, so I oppose this suggestion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I researched about gender neutral pronouns before. You can use "they" when you refer to a *generic* person like everyone or anybody. However, I don't think it's a proper use of "they" when you refer to a *specific* person.

Comment: @MakotoKato: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: @Thomas It's long. Could you tell me which part?

Comment: @user1729 `[Just call people by their name,]`

If the problem is solved by this, I wouldn't open this thread.

Comment: @MakotoKato: I didn't read the whole article, but I was just giving you a reference for the use of *singular they*. There doesn't seem to be anything on this page that says that it can only be generic. Specifically it says in the beginning that *they* can be used when the gender is indeterminate.

Comment: @Thomas Advocates for "singular they" all refer to classic works like Shakespeare as supporting evidences.
However, almost all of the uses in those works are for a generic person.

Comment: @Thomas When you talk about a generic person "everyone", you think of *a certain class* to which "everyone" belongs .
The class consists of *several* persons.
So it seems to be natural to use "they" to refer to them.

Comment: @MakotoKato: I am no language expert. The Wikipedia article does, however, point out that there is a proper use for *singular they* when used in a situation when the gender is indeterminate. It might not be the most common, but it exists. That is the last I have to say about it. Maybe you should try to ask on english.SE about this. If you don't like the *they* options, I am sure you can think of other ways of referring to people with unknown gender.

Comment: @Thomas `[@MakotoKato: I am no language expert. The Wikipedia article does, however, point out that there is a proper use for singular they when used in a situation when the gender is indeterminate. It might not be the most common, but it exists.]`

As I said, you can use "they" to refer to everyone or anybody.
"Everyone" or "anybody" is indeterminate. Regards,

Comment: @Thomas: I linked that in my answer, and Martin Sleziak linked that in a previous comment.

Comment: Here's someone who has a similar opinion to mine.
`[@Mr. Shiny and New: I'm not sure I can explain it very well... Generic they refers to the whole group represented by the singular subject, not to that specific individual. 'Tis meet that some more audience than a mother, since nature makes them partial, should o'erhear the speech. -The pronoun refers to all mothers, and is hence plural, even though "a mother" looks singular. – Marthaª Dec 15 '10 at 21:09]`
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/what-is-the-accepted-stance-on-using-they-in-a-singular-form/6859#6859

Comment: As I said advocates for "singular they" almost always refer to classic works like Shakespeare like this answer:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/what-is-the-accepted-stance-on-using-they-in-a-singular-form/6859#6859

However, they don't seem to care the difference between a generic person and a specific person.
I think this is a big mistake.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ahh, I see. I should pay better attention.

Comment: This is a rather insensitive suggestion. Gender should not be construed as a binary option. Google+ attempted to fix this by adding a third option, "other", which leaves quite a bit to be desired. http://www.theatlanticwire.com/technology/2011/07/google-learns-gender-lesson/39933/

Comment: Well, the edit to the proposal did improve it in terms of sensitivity to members' needs. OTOH adding that third option makes it kinda moot. Anyone who thinks their gender is relevant and wants to disclose it can already do so in their profile.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen `[Anyone who thinks their gender is relevant and wants to disclose it can already do so in their profile. ]`

Of course. But it's easier to check the gender option than to say "I am male. I don't want you to call me her".

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Gender isn't a big deal when logic is involved.

Answer (score 34):

You can write "[they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Gender-neutral_language_movement)".

I don't think that the feature request is very good, and [this discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9227/why-do-women-participate-less-on-our-site-using-their-real-names) might help to shed some light on the topic. (In a nutshell, the presence of female users online is still often accompanied by harassment.)

Moreover, much like many users won't fill in their real name, there's no reason to believe that people would bother to fill in this field in the profile, or their true gender if they do.

Comment: I don't think so.
You can write "they" when you refer to a generic person like everyone, anybody.
However, I don't think it's proper use of "they" when you refer to a *specific* person.

Comment: If you recall the OP of this post, *they* have commented above me.

Comment: @user1729: They sure did! :-)

Comment: I still prefer switching gender. If the guy I am referring to is offended then she can tell me.

Comment: @user1729 I think that's a hassle. Please think about these kind of things happen all the time.

Comment: @user1729: English is easy. In Hebrew a lot of the words have a gender difference (usually a suffix for the female form). It's sometimes easy to forget this is not the case in other languages.

Comment: @Makoto: You are free to think that.

Comment: @MakotoKato My switching gender idea wasn't really meant as serious. However, I entirely agree with Asaf's answer (although I suspect discrimination is not going to be rife here).

Comment: Maybe this question would be a good candidate for migration to [Meta English StackExchange](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/), since a positive response to the request would require a system-wide change anyway. I'm sure users there would have very informed opinions to share on this matter, @MakotoKato, what do you think?

Comment: @Alexander: Perhaps a fresh thread would be better?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I want this question to stay here.
Anybody is free to ask the same question there.

Comment: @AsafKaragila `[You can write "they".]`
Have you used "they" when you refer to a member whose gender is unknown?

Comment: @Makoto: Yes. I often use "the OP" or "the answerer"; but I have used "they". No, I don't have any links at my disposal with examples of that use.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you "singular they" in a formal document?

Comment: @Makoto: What formal document?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Suppose you are a professor on politics, would you use "singular they" in your academic paper?

Comment: @Makoto: Suppose that pigs can fly, will Jews find them kosher?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Okay. Do you use "singular they" in your academic paper?

Comment: @Makoto: I don't know what situation is there when I have to do that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You cite someone's paper whose gender you don't know.

Comment: @Makoto: I'll find out through searching and asking people.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What if you still cannot find out *their* gender?

Comment: @Makoto: That's not a probable scenario (although possible, one need not plan for improbable scenario in most cases - this one included).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Come on.

Comment: @Makoto: I take pride in my ability to locate information that I am interested in. That was not sarcasm.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm asking if you use "singular they" in such a situation. Whether the situation is unlikely or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @Makoto: The fact that the situation is improbable means that I don't know what I'd do in that situation. It depends on *so many* variables, none of which I can even foresee because I have no idea how I'll get into this sort of situation in the first place. Therefore any answer I gave it useless and hypothetical. So let's assume that my answer is the answer you would like to hear.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Yes, that is the preferred standard. Personally, it has happened when I discuss, for example, answers posted by pseudonymous users in MO. (Cannot currently provide a link, though, as it is part of a text in preparation that keeps not being quite done.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila `[@Makoto: The fact that the situation is improbable means that I don't know what I'd do in that situation. It depends on so many variables, none of which I can even foresee because I have no idea how I'll get into this sort of situation in the first place. Therefore any answer I gave it useless and hypothetical. So let's assume that my answer is the answer you would like to hear.]`

As I said, whether it's unlikely or not is irrelevant.
This is just a question whether you use "singular they" in an academic paper or not.
What's so difficult to answer?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo `[@MakotoKato: Yes, that is the preferred standard.]`
Could you provide supporting evidences for your claim?

Comment: @Makoto: Because I can only answer **honestly** questions that I can imagine. You can equally ask me if I would eat a man if we were stranded in the international space station. It's highly improbable that I'll get there, and even then that we get stranded. So I don't know what to tell you. If the situation came that I have exhausted my other options, I might use "they" and I might change the paragraph so I won't have to. **I DON'T KNOW, BECAUSE I CAN'T IMAGINE THAT SORT OF SITUATION.** If you want me to start lying to you, please let me know.

Comment: @AsafKaragila `[@Makoto: Because I can only answer honestly questions that I can imagine. You can equally ask me if I would eat a man if we were stranded in the international space station. It's highly improbable that I'll get there, and even then that we get stranded. So I don't know what to tell you.]`
Let's stop arguing here.
I think it's getting counterproductive.

Answer (score 5):

I think the feature would still be uncomfortable to use. This is because you need to check the profile of everyone whom you write a comment to. I rarely check the profiles of people I am writing comments to. I also guess that many users  would share this habit with me.

Comment: I beg to differ in the sense that I nearly always check the profile of whoever I am answering to. How else could I try to, e.g. ascertain the level of an answer? Granted in those cases where this bit of information would be the most useful, the profile will often not contain any information at all. Also, the question/answer itself contains many clues about the desired level.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, it was just a guess and it turns out to be false in your case.

Comment: Can't argue with that :-)